# The pixel on IE6

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

In my project,I use bootstrap and less. Although when I test the template, it look beautiful, but when test it using ieTest, I found something wrong.

The pictures are, from top to bottom, Chrome 22, IE9 and IE6:
[image: test on the Chrome22]
[image: test on the IE9]
[image: test on the IE6]

I found all I can find, eg "three pixel jog", but I still can't solve it.

here is the html code:

```
<p class="top-tag">
    <span class="floatbutton">
        <a href="" class="clear left-button">&lt;</a>
        <a href="" class="right-button clear">&gt;</a>
     </span>

    <a href="" class="down">down</a>
    <a href="" class="ask-detail">ask phone</a>
    <a href="" class="bytime">time</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;
    <a href="" class="passrate">rate</a>
    <b>1,10</b>
</p>
```

here is the css:

```
p.top-tag {
    margin-top: 25px; 
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    a.down, a.ask-detail {
        display: inline-block; 
        height: 25px; 
        text-align: center; 
        line-height: 25px; 
        border: 1px solid #dddddd; 
        color: #2f2725;
    }
    a.down { width: 44px;}
    a.ask-detail {
        width: 90px;
        margin: 0 43px auto 20px;
    }
    b {
        margin-left: 284px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    span.floatbutton { 
        float: right;
        width: 39px;
        //display: inline-block;
        overflow: auto;
        zoom: 1;

        //for the IE6
        //---
        //_overflow: hidden; zoom: 1; 
        //---
        height: 25px;
        margin: 4px -3px auto 0;
        a {
            display: inline-block; 
            vertical-align: top; 
            width: 13px; 
            height: 13px; 
            border: 1px solid #ddd; 
            padding-left: 4px; 
            padding-bottom: 4px;
        }
        a.left-button {
            float: left; 
            display: inline;  
            border-right-style: none; 
            *margin-top: 1px;
        }
    }
}
```

I use the `bootstrap.css` and `css.less` at the beginning of the template.

The question is why the pixel under the IE, they can't work. And the IE6 they can't display, and float far.

Thanks!

Comment: IE6? _Why?????_

Comment: Because IE6 is 10 year old technologies you really not need to put time to write this post. Just search google and enough Help will be provided :)

Comment: IE6 *should be* obsolete, but please be polite. There are still people using it who might not have a choice, so designing to account for them is the nice thing to do.

Comment: sorry,I just want to make under all the browsers,it looks better.someone also use IE6,you can't make all people use the chrome!

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't support IE6, period. It is a 12 year old browser. Facebook, Twitter, and YouTube didn't exist when it was introduced. You can't make people use Chrome, but you can make them use IE7 at the very least. Things **will never look perfect in IE6 if you want to have any sort of modern website**.

Comment: Also: even **Microsoft** says "it's time to say goodbye" to IE6. http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: If you really _need_ to support IE6, you are better of with table. If your project is small enough, or you have that enough time and energy, you can write two (or more) sets of pages, and use conditional comment to separate them.